Interpolation `$()` does not work for Docker command in Ubuntu 22.04
According this article, to remove all images, the command
sudo docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)

must be executed. AFAIK it does not work in Windows, but I need the CLI mainly for VPS. Currently, I have Ubuntu 22.04 in VPS. If to execute above command, the error
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Head "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images


will occur. Similar error for removing of all containers:
sudo docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)

permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.44/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22status%22%3A%7B%22exited%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers

The Docker version:
Client: Docker Engine - Community

 Version:           25.0.4
 API version:       1.44
 Go version:        go1.21.8
 Git commit:        1a576c5
 Built:             Wed Mar  6 16:32:12 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default


do you mean to do $(sudo docker ps ...) ?

You need sudo in front of the nested docker command.
Instead of
sudo docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)

you need
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -a -q)

If you use Docker a lot, consider adding yourself to the docker group. Then you can run the docker command without adding sudo in front every time. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user
Most tutorials etc. assume that you're part of the docker group, so when they show commands to run, they'll show them without sudo.
